# $x_n \to a \iff x_n\in U$ where $U$ is an open neighborhood

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Let there be a metric space $M$ and let $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $M$ and $a\in M$ then: $x_n\to a\iff$ for all open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ there is an $N$ s.t for all $N<n$ we have $x_n\in U$

$x_n\to a$ then, by definition for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that for all  $N<n$ we have $d(x_n,a)<\varepsilon$ $\iff$

$\iff$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that for all  $N<n$ we have $x_n\in B(a,\varepsilon)$ and every open ball is an open set or in every open set there is a ball contained in it (by definition of an open set) $\iff$

$\iff$ So $x_n\in B(a,\varepsilon)$ is and open set and $a\in B(a,\varepsilon)$ because $a\in B(a,\varepsilon)\to d(a,a)=0<\varepsilon$ and therefore $x_n\in B(a,\varepsilon)$ is an open neighborhood.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: In the last 'paragraph' I don't know why you put $B(a , \epsilon ) \rightarrow d(a, a)=0 $. I think you know intuitively the result but your proof is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \in U $ and $U$ open then there is some $\epsilon >0 $ such that $B(a, \epsilon )\subset U.$ We can take $n$ large enough so that $x_n $ is in the ball and so lies in $U$. Here we use the fact that $x_n$ converges to $a$.

For the converse it's simply because $B(a, \epsilon)$ is an open neighbourhood of $a$ for each $\epsilon >0$. So by assumption for each $\epsilon >0 $ we can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N$ then $x_n \in B(a, \epsilon ).$ So $d(x_n, a )<\epsilon $.